# The word order in a sentence. Why "are" follows "listed"?

Tags: meaning, word-order

I have a sentence: "Often listed with verbs followed only by an infinitive are the verbs: .... ."

I think I can change this word order to: "The verbs: .... are often listed with verbs followed only by an infinitive."

Am I right? The first sentence is very difficult for me and I can hardly understand its meaning without changing the word order.

Comment: ***The verbs** [**which / that are**] often listed with verbs followed only by an infinitive **ARE ...** [some list of verbs]* is the standard English "Subject + Verb + Object" sequence, but in this case the "object / complement" has been "fronted" (moved to the *front* of the sentence) for stylistic effect. Your "rephrasing" is incorrect - consider carefully why I included ***which / that are*** in my version.

Comment: The following verbs are often listed as verbs followed only by an infinitive: [list of verbs]

Comment: @FumbleFingers your version of this sentence is really nice. I like it. But, unfortunately, I don't see the difference in meaning in your version and mine. Yes, our sequences are different and my one looks bad, but I can't understand why it is incorrect(

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh sorry. I think I understand. Your version is the standard English sequence. OK. I'll remember it

Comment: I *hope* your last comment means you've noticed that my version includes ***which / that*** - without which you can't make a syntactically valid sequence very easily.

Comment: Yours (the OP) is not a sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK. But, e.g. I've already listed the verbs above. And now I can say: "These verbs (which are above) ARE often listed with verbs followed..." Write? If yes, I still don't see the difference. And Lambie says that my sentence is not a sentence. But why? "These verbs ARE listed..." or "The verbs: [some list] ARE listed..." It still seems to me the same... But, I know now and remember that it's not the standard)

Comment: Yes, OK, I really understand what you all mean) my sentence is correct grammatically but it's inconvenient to understand

Comment: Well, obviously we don't have a *complete* "sentence" here, because we don't have the actual list of verbs - just an ellipsis. And the sentence doesn't look like it was written by a native speaker anyway. Even if I accept that there can be such a thing as "verbs [which are] followed only by an infinitive", I don't understand why there should be some *other* verbs that are often listed [together] with them. But that's what the structure implies.

Answer (score 4):

Your reasoning is correct. A possible reason for writing the sentence as it was, is that with a list like this, it's common to first state the definition of the list, and the list itself is put at the end. In your rewritten sentence, I'm first reading a list of words and I have no idea what the author wants to say about them (other than that they're all verbs).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think it's correct to write as it was, but it's rather difficult to understand. I couldn't understand what the word "listed" meant in its position in the sentence